# SQL Agnet,SSIS packet and Error: DB2 OLEDB not registered perhaps no 64 bit registered SSIS Packet

Tags: sql-server, ssis, agent

I canot execute my SSIS  packet from SQL Agent! I always get this error 
"DB2 OLEDB not registered perhaps no 64 bit registered SSIS Packet"
[image]

I tried everything like deactivate run time 64 to false, also changing the check box in the sql agent to allow the package to run in 32 bit. but noting worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver for the 64 bit was missing, after installing it everything went fine :) .